# Aside from hierarchical data, what are recursive CTEs used for?

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

There are [many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-using-a-recursive-common-table-expression-to-display-multiple-levels-of-recursion) [tutorials](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) [on](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1520/recursive-queries-using-common-table-expressions-cte-in-sql-server/) recursive CTEs. I've noticed that they all use the same examples, usually a "parts explosion" or an HR management chart. Can recursive CTEs be used to solve anything other than this type of hierarchical data? Or is this their target use case?

Comment: of course. For example, to generate date-range

Comment: They can make complex SQL easier to write and understand

Comment: @Sergey sounds cool. Could you show me how that works?

Comment: @Sergey: unless you have a database which supports generating ranges without it ;)

Comment: You can solve sudokus: https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/11/22/sudoku-recursive-common-table-expression-solver/, https://technology.amis.nl/it/solving-a-sudoku-with-one-sql-statement/

Comment: Querying hierarchical data and generating sequences (or filling gaps in existing sequences) are in fact the two main tasks tackled with recursive CTEs. Generally, recursive CTEs are used when you need an iteration in SQL. For instance if you must apply a calculation that is based on the calculation's result for the previous row. But this is rare (much more often we would calculate based on all previous rows, for which we'd simply use analytic window functions).

Comment: Recursive CTEs makes SQL a Turing complete language. So from pure theoretica standpoint: you can use SQL for any kind of computational tasks.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @InStartDate DATE='20210101';
DECLARE @InStopDate DATE='20211231';

WITH CTE AS
(
 SELECT @InStartDate AS DAD
   UNION ALL
 SELECT DATEADD(DD,1,C.DAD)
  FROM CTE AS C
   WHERE C.DAD<@InStopDate
)
SELECT D.DAD
   FROM CTE AS D OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Generate dates range in the SQL Server with recursive CTE